# Which Ninject version should I install from NuGet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, nuget

just a simple question:

I'm going to use Ninject in my **ASP.NET MVC 3** application, but in the Package Manager there seem to be a few options:

- Ninject
- Ninject.MVC3
- Ninject.Web

Among others. Which of these should I install?

Comment: I've been wondering this lately too.  It's confusing because Ninject.MVC3 *was* the unofficial version and was recommended against, but now it seems like it is the official version.  fwiw, I'm avoiding NuGet for Ninject right now because of the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/03/01/ninject-2-2-1-0-and-ninject-mvc3-2-2-1-0-released/

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/02/22/ninject-mvc3-and-ninject-web-mvc3-merged-to-one-package/

The last one is a bit outdated in the mean time, but still contains good information. I try to update it during the comming days.

Comment: Is this still relevant for MVC Web API as well? I noticed on the wiki it mentions that MVC3 package should work for MVC4 as well, so I assume so.

Answer (score 2):

Install `Ninject.MVC3`. The package will automatically install any dependencies it needs (i.e. `Ninject`)

**Edit:**

Looking at [`Ninject.Web.Mvc.nuspec`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/nuget/Ninject.Web.Mvc.nuspec), it looks like it will install `Ninject`<strike>`2.2.0.0`</strike>`2.2.1.0`

Placed proper version. But again, install it directly so that any dependencies  are also automatically installed.

Comment: That's wrong. The file you linked is just a template. It is modified by the build process. A new installation will use 2.2.1.0.